# HTML in a data-attr tag

Tags: html, tooltip, custom-data-attribute

I want to put a link in my Tooltip Text, like for example:

```
<div tooltip="Look at following: <a href='https://google.com/' target='_blank'>Website</a>" flow="right"></div>
```

But if I do so, the tooltip will display the HTML in Text - How can I let the data-attr read Code ? I want to just put a link inside the Text.

Here the Tooltip Code:

CSS:

```
[tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}

[tooltip]::before,
[tooltip]::after {
  text-transform: none; 
  font-size: .9em; 
  line-height: 1;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
[tooltip]::before {
  content: '';
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  z-index: 1001; 
}
[tooltip]::after {
  content: attr(tooltip);*emphasized text*
  min-width: 3em;
  max-width: 21em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

[tooltip='']::before,
[tooltip='']::after {
  display: block;
}

[tooltip][flow^="right"]::before {
  top: 50%;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-color: #333;
  right: calc(0em - 5px);
  transform: translate(.5em, -50%);
}
[tooltip][flow^="right"]::after {
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(100% + 5px);
  transform: translate(.5em, -50%);
}
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: @Rob what about now friend